# Does the included php page can show any info about the requested page? If no, how can I send any?

Tags: php

I have two pages 1.php and 2.php

2.php (which is the secret page) can not be accessed unless the 1.php send him to it.

On 1.php the user log in. So if he login then he can see 2.php

In my code I use `include` and my idea is to send something like a string and it will be checked in 2.php for matching. 2.php must be blank if you access it directly.
How can I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register e session variable on 1.php then read this variable on 2.php.

EDIT:

On 1.php, start the session at the beginnin of the script with:

session_start();

then, register a session variabile if the login was successfull, example:

$_SESSION["login"]=true;

on 2.php:

```
<?
session_start();
if($_SESSION["login"])
{
    // your code here

}
else
{
    echo "Access denied";
}

?>
```

Comment: Hello, can I have an example please?

Comment: How much time does it get to clean the session ?

Comment: It's based on your php.ini and the best is to give a logout link to the user and clear it. Or maybe you want to clear the session at the end of 2.php, after your code executed.

Answer (score 0):

Its typical task for sessions. I recommend you to use sessions and session variables.

So I do it like this:

```
<?php
//this is php 1
session_start();

if($_GET['name']=='Steaven' && $_GET['password']=='abcd') {
   $_SESSION['login']=true;
   // you could use redirect
   header('Location:'php2.php');
}
?>


<?php
//this is php 2
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
   if(!$_SESSION['login']) {
      exit();
   }
} else exit();
?>
```

I hope you can use html forms (for method get.) This is simple code with lot of potential dangerous parts. But in its basics it would work.

Comment: Hi, session_start; must be first function called by php file. So put it at beginning of php document. I also advice you to put before exit function redirection to safer place, e.g. header('Location:'php1.php'); and then call exit function.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

to find the referrer page on page2.php and match it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. However is there any trick that someone can do and access it ?

Comment: Not a secure solution at all. The referer is provided by the client and can hence be faked easily.